# Indices Exchange

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, notation

In General Relativity, we often face indices exchange; but I actually do not really understand how to change indices properly.
For example:
If I have

$$ R_{ab}\partial_c \phi \partial^b\phi \delta g^{ac}$$

then I want to change indices "$c$" become "$b$", which one is correct?

$$  1. \hspace{0.5 cm} R_{ab}\partial_b \phi \partial^b\phi \delta g^{ab}$$
or
$$  2. \hspace{0.5 cm} R_{ac}\partial_b \phi \partial^c\phi \delta g^{ab}$$

Comment: In the second equation I just simply change indices "b" to become "c"  and indices "c" to become "b".

Comment: Now the second is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example all indices are dummy indices, $a,b,c$ all denote summation and the expression is a scalar. If you want to rename the index $b$ to $c$ then the index $c$ should be changed to some other index for example $d$ or $b$. The expession will remain the same as long as all indices denote summation. For example:

$$ R_{ab}\partial_c \phi \partial^b\phi \delta g^{ac} = R_{ac}\partial_b \phi \partial^c\phi \delta g^{ab}$$

where i swap $c$ with $b$ and $b$ with $c$.

Keep in mind that the same index can appear only one time up and one time down in the same expression. Expressions like:

$$T_{adc}R^{adc}S_{cda}$$

are meaningless.